# Why is my code skipping straight to else?

Tags: python

I’m having trouble with a python `for` loop containing `re.match` skipping the `if` and jumping right to the `else`, so the loop always returns `"none"`. The `if` will work if I don’t have the else.

Here’s the code:

```
def searchBegin (searchChar):
    regex = searchChar
    regex += '.{2,7}'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    for (offset, line) in enumerate(lines):
        if re.match(pattern, line):
            return line
            break
        else:
            return 'none'
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is currently happening is that your first line doesn't have a match, so the loop goes into the else block in the first iteration, and returns `none` directly.

Instead, you can do something like below, where the `none` is returned after the end of the for loop, and you just print a `no match` otherwise:

```
def searchBegin (searchChar):
    regex = searchChar
    regex += '.{2,7}'
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    for (offset, line) in enumerate(lines):
        if re.match(pattern, line):
            return line
            break
        else:
            print "no match"
    return 'none'
```